# Is there a simple (possibly obfuscated) math expression for the number of days in a given month?

Tags: date, assembly, micro-optimization

For use in cases where a standard library is not available. Assume that the month is given as an unsigned integer.

I'd be interested in seeing the shortest arithmetic expression that gives the correct answer, allowing or disallowing bitwise operators & masks but not lookup tables. Partial expressions can be saved into a variable for readability to showcase the idea used.

Comment: What do you mean "allowing or disallowing bitwise operators & masks but not lookup tables". So are bitwise ops allowed? Are lookup tables allowed?

Comment: `((((M+9)%12)%5)+1)%2 + 30` handles all but February, yet after seeing [sweetness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62546633/2410359), why continue?

Comment: A lookup table is the correct solution if you care about fast, readable code. If you need slow, unreadable code, well... have fun with that. This question smells like borderline code golf.

Comment: saolof, @Lundin [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546115/is-there-a-simple-possibly-obfuscated-math-expression-for-the-number-of-days-i#comment110617416_62546115) is fair.  Why not not use a lookup table?

Comment: Original context for my question was in assembly code, where lookup tables are outright painful.

Comment: And of course, given the question format, using a lookup is the trivial solution

Comment: Small lookup tables aren't painful in many forms of assembly language, either to maintain or for performance.  Especially common embedded ISAs like ARM where the difference between memory speed and CPU speed isn't nearly as huge as modern x86.  (On modern x86-64, implementing a 2-bit lookup table by shifting an immediate is a nice trick, though.)

Comment: @saolof you still didn't answer my question about what you mean by "allowing or disallowing".

Comment: @BeeOnRope Both answers with or without are useful. Using bitwise arithmetic is much better for platforms that support it. Solutions that don't use bitwise arithmetic are going to be less performant but arguably more portable.

Comment: @saolof - maybe our definitions are not the same, but basic bitwise stuff like and, or is supported by any platform, even small MCUs. I guess stuff like variable shift varies, but I expect it to be at least as common as multiply.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an approach that uses only four simple arithmetic and bitwise ops and a 26-bit constant:

```
int days_in_month(unsigned m) {
    //              121110 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
    return 28 + ((0b11101110111110111011001100u >> m * 2u) & 0b11);
}
```

If you also want to handle leap year (no mention of it in the question), you can take a similar approach, at the cost of a few more operations and a 50-bit constant:

```
int days_in_month2(unsigned m, bool ly) {
    return 28 + ((0b11101110111110111011011111101110111110111011001100u >> (m + 12*ly) * 2u) & 0b11);
}
```

If you are willing the pass the leap year in a different way, e.g., setting a bit like `month | 16` to indicate leap year, it would be more efficient.

I assume you pass the month as 1 to 12, not 0 to 11.

Tests and generated asm can be seen [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ed99Ss).

Comment: Great approach! One minor variation would be:
 28 | (0b1111101011111010111111111010111110101111010011110000u >> (4*m | 2*ly) & 0b11)

Which handles month lengths with leap years in six assembly instructions much like in https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62547215/1 , but replacing one LEA instruction with a movabs instruction according to godbolt

Answer (score 2):

Variation om [@BeeOnRope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62546633/2410359) nice answer.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int DaysPerMonth(int Month, bool IsLeapYear) {
  assert(Month >= 1 && Month <= 12);
  // 0b11101110111110111011001100u
  //   3 B   B   E   E   C   C
  return (((0x3BBEECCu | (IsLeapYear << 2*2)) >> Month*2) & 3) + 28;
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  for (int ly = 0; ly <= 1; ly++) {
    for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
      printf("(%2d %2d), ", m, DaysPerMonth(m,ly));
    }
    puts("");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force answer in pseudocode for readability:

```
monthlength(month,is_leapyear) :=
    oddmonth = ( month + (month >= 8) ? 1 : 0) % 2  // Or  (month ^ (month >> 3))&1 
    feb_days_offset = (month == 2) ? 2 - is_leapyear : 0
    return 30 + oddmonth - feb_days_offset
```

Where month >= 8 can also be implemented with a bitshift since it's just the fourth bit in an unsigned representation, so that oddmonth is (first bit) xor (fourth bit), which can be consisely written as (month ^ (month >> 3))&1 . Similarly, subtracting the feb offset can be thought of as flipping the second bit on febuary, and flipping the first bit during leap year february.

single line with no intermediate variables:

```
monthlength(month,isleapyear) := 30 + ( month + (month >= 8 ? 1 : 0)) % 2 - (month==2 ? (2 - isleapyear) : 0)
```

Alternatively, one that uses exclusively bitwise arithmetic and shifts using the tricks discussed above:

```
monthlength(month,leapyear) := 30 ^ (month==2)<<1 ^ (month==2)&leapyear ^ (month^month>>3)&1
```

Comment: Using a ternary is probably a better idea than multiplying by a boolean.  Most compilers will make branchless code either way, but `month==2 ? 2-leapyear : 0` looks clearer for humans.  You definitely don't want any compiler to actually make a boolean 0/1 and multiply by it, especially on an embedded CPU without fast HW multiply.  (e.g. in debug mode, or with a crappy vendor-supplied compiler.)

Comment: Agreed. Had it there in the pseudocode form mainly due to the bitshift trick, and ended up wanting to make things consistent.

Comment: Ended up changing the given answer. Also makes the expression copy-pasteable to more languages.

Comment: I doubt most compilers are going to optimize `( month + (month >= 8 ? 1 : 0)) % 2` into `(month >> 3) & month`.  For one because that's only even valid if value-range analysis can prove there aren't bits set beyond the 4th.  If you want it to be usefully copy-pastable into common low-level languages, definitely write it as a shift.

Comment: Did a bit more code golfing & inspecting assembly output. Multiplying by a boolean with a decent C compiler compiles to the same code as a ternary with zero.

Ended up with bitwise arithmetic versions that don't use addition at all, since everything is about setting the last two bits anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int m, leapyr, y ;

//m = month range is 1 to 12

//y = year range is 00 to 99

leapyr = ( ( y & 0x03 ) && 1 ); //0 means leap year and 1 means Non leap year

m = 30 + ( ( m  & 1 ) ^ ( 1 && ( m & 8 ) ) ) - ( ( !( m & 13 ) ) ) - ( ( !( m & 13 ) ) & leapyr );
```

My answer is considering year. If you don't want to use assign leapyr variable 0 or 1 as you wish.